# GVim Shows Python Support Error When Opening

Tags: python, gvim, vimrc

Every time I open up gVim there is an error that says that Python is not supported. I have checked numerous websites and everything that I have tried does not seem to work. In my vimrc file, I have included the dll file directory and I have made sure that gVim and Python are both 64bit. I need python to work if I want to use the YouCompleteMe Plugin for Vim.

When I type `echo has ('python3')` in vim it returns `0` instead of `1`.

Also when I type `python3 print(1)` this is the error that pops up

````
E370: Could not load library C:\Users\nikhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python38.dll
E263: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python library could not be loaded.```
````

- Error Message When Opening up gVIm
  [image: Error Message When Opening up gVIm]
- My vimrc File
  [image: My vimrc File]

Comment: I know nothing about gvim, but try to check its version. In no gui vim `vim --version` gives you options, Vim was compiled with. If it has no +python3 option in the output, then nothing you can do, except recompile or find one which was compiled with this option.

Comment: It's most likely that you gvim was compiled without python3 support

Comment: could you remove `set pythondll=...` restart gvim and show output of `echo &pythondll` and `echo &pythonthreedll`?

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/): we would prefer you to actually paste the text of your vimrc (either here or to a pastebin/gist-like service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `:version` of your gvim. It should have `+python3/dyn` there for the python3 support.

Both python3 and gvim should be 64 bit. (Windows binaries from vim.org are 32bit)

Then try adding to your vimrc:

```
set pythonthreedll=python38.dll
set pythonthreehome=C:/Users/nikhi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/
```